# Один вопрос о параллельном выполнении в Java

Tags: java, concurrency

Допустим, есть. Метод выполняется в нескольких потоках.

```
 private void removeNetworkFromSimulation(final SimulationSessionAgents session, final SimulationBaseEntity baseEntity) {
        for (final MobileCoreAgent mcAgent : session.getCoreAgents().values())
            session.requestAction(mcAgent.getCoreId(), new CrossThreadRunnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Collection<ConnectivityLink> links = ((EpcVsVepcModel) session.getSimulationModel()).getLinks();
                            CoreSimulator.requestLinksRemoval(CommonUtils.getInLinks(baseEntity, links), mcAgent);
                            CoreSimulator.requestLinksRemoval(CommonUtils.getOutLinks(baseEntity, links), mcAgent);
                            mcAgent.getCoreSimulator().removeAgent(baseEntity.getNcID());
                        }
                    }
            );

    }
```

Будет ли он потокобезопасным?

Вот эта строка:

```
session.requestAction(mcAgent.getCoreId(), new CrossThreadRunnable() {
```

Означает, что в одном потоке, в очереди будет выполнен код `run()` безымянного класса CrossThreadRunnable.

Comment: Читаю как раз книжку интересную, дык вот, что в ней пишут. Может, пригодится.
![][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/E67qr5p.jpg

Comment: ) не, это не то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В пакете concurrent есть замечательный класс ReentrantLock, используй его дабы обезопасить выполнение своего кода. Блокируй поток на выполнении перед вызовом метода и снимай блокировку после выполнения.

```
private static final ReentrantLock rl = new ReentantLock();

....

try{
rl.lock();
...
} finally{
 rl.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Блокировать потоки   концептуально неверно.  <br/>  <br></br>(*вот тут нужно вставить перевод строки*, но у меня не получается)  Блокировать надо доступ к данным, которые нельзя использовать одновременно.

Comment: @avp, похоже, что комментарии [вообще не поддерживают перевод строки](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @Etki, а мне показалось, что [раздел Linebreaks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks) как раз про это.  Только не работает (о чудо, оказывается в важен символ в конце строки перед двумя пробелами).  Поправка -- чудо отменяется. Online (в момент набора) я увидел, как текст (после ввода точки и затем 2-х пробелов) начался с новой строки, а после ввода всего комментария этот перенос пропал.  **Так что вопрос остается открытым**.